# Laravel user input get value

Tags: laravel

I'm new so I will give a very simplified question: I have a this view:

```
   {{Form::label('Enter number 1 to 10')}} {{Form::text('customerid')}}
    <button  type="button" View</button>
```

When this button is selected I want to retrieve the record in the customer table(based on the number entered) and display(name, address, city, state etc.) on another view. I have the other view created and tested but my problem is passing the user input.

Comment: What is the specific question?

Comment: When the input is submitted? When a user types something? When the user clicks the field? We need when, and we need to see what you've tried.

Comment: This current code won't submit anything. `type='button'` needs to be `type='submit'` for starters. The class you're looking for in your controller code is `Input::get('fieldname')` if you're using laravel 4

Comment: You need to add `<form>` tags arround the input fields. Also, the button has to be of the type `submit`

Comment: Read the book from Dayle Reese! It's very good for Laravel beginners. http://daylerees.com/codebright

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the opening and closing form tags as well as the fact that your label is passing the text to appear as the first parameter which should be the label identifier as well.

So your form should look something like this:

```
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
    {{ Form::label('number', 'Enter numbers from 1 to 10') }}
    {{ Form::text('number')}} 
    {{ Form::submit('Click Me!')}} 
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Hope this helps

**Edit:**

Once you submit it you get the input by doing the following :

In Laravel 5

```
$number = Request::input('number');
```

In Laravel 4

```
$number = Input::get('number');
```

Note that the name you put inside the `input()` or `get()` (depending on which version of laravel you are using)  is basically the name of the field. If you desire to get all the input and assign it to a variable (which I am doing only for one value in the example above) then use the option `all()` instead or `get()` or `input()` in both of the examples above. 
In theory would be:

```
$input = Request::all();
```

Or

```
$input = Input::all();
```

Hope this solves your problem.